# How to import a class with composition from a module?

Tags: python, class, import, composition

Assuming I have a module `example.py` with the following two classes. One containing the other:

```
#example.py
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,name):
        Self.name=name

class Company():
    def __init__(self,company,boss):
        Self.company=company
        self.boss = Employee(boss)
```

If I want to instantiate company in other file called `work.py` I go:

```
#work.py
from example import Company
mycompany=company('bmw','michael)
```

This code seems to work. Now I don't understand why because how does python know about the class `Employee` in the file `work.py`?

Would the code be "safer" in work.py if I do:

```
from example import Company, Employee
```

Comment: Your code does not know, but `company` knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`work.py` doesn't need to know about it. `Company.__init__` has its own reference to the global scope of `example` where the free variable `Employee` is looked up.

```
>>> from example import Company
>>> Company.__init__.__globals__['Employee']
<class 'example.Employee'>
```

`from example import Company` creates a new global variable in `work.py` that is initialized using `example.Company`. Since `Company.__init__` doesn't know or care about the global scope of `work.py`, there's no need to create an additional `Employee` global there.

Comment: Is this exactly the same as when I actually would import Employee as well?

Comment: Yes. The module `example` is its own object, with its own global scope. The names you define in the global scope of `work` aren't used by anything defined in `example`. Python is *lexically* scoped.

Comment: What I failed to understand when I started learning Python was, that when you import a file, the whole file gets executed at the line of the import. That means all the objects defined in the resulting module are „there“. The `from…import` only controls what the _importing module_ is allowed to see from them.

Comment: in this question I can not go into more detail but the wondering continues, because python sees that other classes have to be imported, look for them, and get them. but if it is a variable that is not the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046564/python-importing-class-with-composition