# What happens when python imports a class with composition?

Tags: python, class, import, composite

Despite of this question being answered:
[How to import a class with composition from a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040854/how-to-import-a-class-with-composition-from-a-module)
I still don't understand the functioning of importing composite classes in python.

The following is a kind of long code but very basic. In a file called example.py there are three classes, Employee, Car and Company. Company calls Employee and employee calls Car.
Employee has a static method which does not work, simply returns a variable that does not exists.

example.py:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    
    def add_employee_atribute(self):
        if ' ' in self.name:
            self.completename='created with method class: ^' + self.name.title()
    
    def upperit(self):
        return self.name.upper()
        
    @staticmethod
    def empstatic(myname):
        return myname+myname
    
    @staticmethod
    def empstatic_wrong():
        # this is wrong
        return ERROR
    
    def add_car(self,make):
        self.car = Car(make)

class Car():
    def __init__(self, make):
        self.car = make
    
class Company():
    def __init__(self,name,people):
        self.name=name
        self.employees=[] 
        for person in people:
            self.employees.append(Employee(person))
        
    def get_all_employess(self):
        return 'These are all: ' + ', '.join([e.name for e in self.employees])
    
    def get_employee(self,name):
        for e in self.employees:
            if e.name == name:
                return e
```

Now if I want to use Company in a file I go:

work.py:

```
from example import Company
C = Company('kodak',['peter','john smith'])
C.employees[1].add_employee_atribute()
C.get_all_employess()
peter = C.get_employee('peter')
peter.add_car('BMW')
```

This all works.

Python seems to evaluate the imported code (Company) in work.py in a way that realises that Company needs Employee and Employee needs Car. Very clever. So it looks like python looks for the classes when they are called. Nevertheless python does not realise that the variable 'ERROR' does not exist.

So what puzzles me is the fact that python is able to distinguish, look for the composite classes but not for the variables.
Some explanation about this?

Comment: Where do you define `ERROR`? How do you use it in `work.py`? If I do, for example `ERROR = 5` in `example.py`, then `C.employees[0].empstatic_wrong()` works. When you import a script, the whole script is executed, so the names for `Employee`, `Car`, etc are all defined there and they can be looked up. When you import a specific name from a module, the module is imported (check `sys.modules.keys()`) but only the thing you imported is introduced by name in your current script.

Comment: You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Names are looked up (in the appropriate scope) when they are needed, and names in a function are not needed until you actually execute the function. There is *no* distinction between names that refer to classes and names that refer to objects. (In fact, classes are just objects of a particular type.)

Comment: If `Employee` weren't defined, `Company.__init__` wouldn't notice until you actually tried to instantiate `Company`. You could still import the module just fine.

Comment: @reti43 that means that "from example import Company and " import example" are memorywise the same only that in the first case I can refer Company by name directly (as opposed to example.Company)

Comment: @Reti43 moreover, it looks like in composition it is really advisable to have all the classes in one file. Except if they are imported at the start.